# Installing Tata Photon Plus Dialer-Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: networking, internet, usb-modem

I am using Ubuntu-13.10. I bought a new Tata Photon Plus Prepaid connection (EC-156 Modem). I installed the dialer in my Windows Desktop Pc and it went fine. I tried to install the dialer software in my laptop with Ubuntu. I saw the manual and i was told that after inserting the modem to the system i can find the device in /media. But even after waiting for long time i couldn't see the files in that folder. Only if i can go to that location i can install the dialer software as said by the manual. But i can use the modem to connect to internet from the networks menu available at the top. What is the Problem? Why i couldn't install the Dialer?

---

Output of lsblk:
[image: lsblk]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go into the `/media/device-UUID` via terminal and then run `ls` command to lists it's contents.

Comment: It says No such file or directory.

Comment: post the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: Posted in the Question.

Comment: mount `sr1` and run the `lsblk` command.And post your device mountpoint.

Comment: Should i use mount sr1?
It says mount: can't find sr1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab

Comment: let us discuss here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the files on the modem,run the below commands one by one on terminal,

```
sudo mkdir /media/modem
sudo mount /dev/sr1 /media/modem
```

your modem will be mounted on `/media/modem`.You can go there and view the files in it.

Comment: I have a problem. After doing this, each time i boot into ubuntu it says the medium cannot be mounted. "Press S to skip or M to manually mount." I don't want this step. How to remove this?

Comment: you can ask it as a question.

Comment: Since this is the effect of the above question i am asking it here.

Comment: ask as another question with a link to this,somebody will help you.